# remove shadow of a button when its active ( clicked )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this CSS for buttons animation and else :

```
.btnliner {
    background: url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -105px;
    /* Fallback */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(../images/stripes.png) no-repeat 0px 0px, url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.btnliner:hover {
    background: url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -5px;
    /* Fallback */
    background: url(../images/stripes.png) no-repeat 0px -200px, url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -8px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

and this is my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button1").css("border", "3px solid red");
            $("#button1").css("backgroundimage", "url (../images/btnbg.png)", "!important");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button2").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button2").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#button3").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button3").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button4").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button4").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button5").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button5").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button5").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button5").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button6").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button6").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button7").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button7").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button8").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button8").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button9").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button9").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});
```

When I click a button, the background still have a gray shadow on it. What I want is when I click the button, the css animation stops and I can see the background image of that button, and when I click another button, all buttons go to default style ( gray shadow on them ) and only the button that I clicked, show the background without any shadows on it.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: Wow! heaps of `.ready`! you must merge all of them into one.

Comment: This seems to be the outline property. Use `btnliner:active{outline:0}` in your css

Comment: All your functions seem to do the same thing. It might be better to give your html elements the same class, and use $(this) in the javascript instead of the current name.

Comment: @jbutler483 i want the outline , but i dont want the shadow on the background image f button, when its clicked

Comment: @Aria: could you provide a working demo (including the html?) at least that way we can see what you're talking about. Also, that js could be improved by using a single `$(document).ready({});` clause, meaning it doesn't need to be rewritten for every function

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".myButton").on('click', function () {
          $(this).addClass('extraClass');
       });
   });

Using only css and maybe adding a new class on click to have a new background should take care of your needs.

Comment: You can also try to remove shadow on `:hover` css. Here is the http://fiddle.jshell.net/d0xoc4w2/

Comment: @LinkinTED this is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/freshboy/o1mzpmts/1/

Comment: @Aria: always remember to mark as answer to the appropriate answer. It may help some one.

Answer (score 0):

This is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/freshboy/o1mzpmts/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button1").css("border", "3px solid red");
            $("#button1").css("backgroundimage", "url (../images/btnbg.png)", "!important");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.btnliner:active {
//Put all your shadows in here and set them to 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.btnliner').on('click', function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
    $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
        $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
        $('.btnliner').removeClass('active');
        btn.addClass('active');
    });
 });
});
```

and css:

```
.active {
    border: 3px solid red;
    background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -5px;
}
```

[Final Answer](http://jsfiddle.net/shubhambhave/u85Ldsj6/)