# Remove Button's Shadow when its active ( clicked )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/freshboy/o1mzpmts/1/)

I have this CSS for buttons animation and else :

```
.btnliner {
    background: url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -105px;
    /* Fallback */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(../images/stripes.png) no-repeat 0px 0px, url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.btnliner:hover {
    background: url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -5px;
    /* Fallback */
    background: url(../images/stripes.png) no-repeat 0px -200px, url(../images/btnbg.png) no-repeat center -8px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

and this is my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button1").css("border", "3px solid red");
            $("#button1").css("backgroundimage", "url (../images/btnbg.png)", "!important");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button2").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button2").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#button3").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button3").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button4").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button4").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button5").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button5").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button5").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button5").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button6").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button6").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button7").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button7").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button8").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button8").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button9").on('click', function () {
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('button').css("border", "hidden");
            $("#button9").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    });
});
```

When I click a button, the background still have a gray shadow on it. What I want is when I click the button, the css animation stops and I can see the background image of that button, and when I click another button, all buttons go to default style ( gray shadow on them ) and only the button that I clicked, show the background without any shadows on it.

Comment: box-shadow: none; is what you are looking for. You would be better creating an active class and add and remove that as you need it

Comment: @Andrew , no , i want the shadow on the image of button removed . check the demo

Comment: Thats not what your title says. it says remove the shadow

Comment: seems you have added simmilar 2 questions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321362/remove-shadow-of-a-button-when-its-active-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Edit: set originial background again on click and keep the class to selected button only.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.btnliner').on('click', function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
    $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
        $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
        $('.btnliner').removeClass('active');
        btn.addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.active{
     border: 3px solid red;
     background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -5px;
 }
```

Check fiddle: [Final Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/shubhambhave/u85Ldsj6/)

Comment: not worked , i dont mean the box shadow , i mean the shadow on the image of button which has some animations

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code a little bit (just the js) ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: none;
}
button {
  width: 190px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  position: fixed;
  border: hidden;
}
.btnliner {
  background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -105px;
  /* Fallback */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: url(http://s22.postimg.org/tz88bokup/stripes.png) no-repeat 0px 0px, url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -8px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.btnliner:hover {
  background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -5px;
  /* Fallback */
  background: url(http://s22.postimg.org/tz88bokup/stripes.png) no-repeat 0px -200px, url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -8px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.active {
  border: 3px solid red;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a class="one txtbox1"> Text1 </a>

  <a class="two txtbox1">Text2</a>

  <a class="three txtbox1">text3 </a>

  <a class="four txtbox1">text4 </a>

  <a class="five txtbox1">text5 </a>

  <a class="six txtbox1">text6 </a>

  <a class="seven txtbox1">text 7 </a>

  <a class="eight txtbox1">text 8 </a>

  <a class="nine txtbox1">text9 </a>


  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button1" data-target="one" class="btnliner">محصولات</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button2" data-target="two" class="btnliner">مشتریان</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button3" data-target="three" class="btnliner">سیستم های داخلی</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button4" data-target="four" class="btnliner">تیکتینگ</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button5" data-target="five" class="btnliner">فروم</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button6" data-target="six" class="btnliner">دانش های مرتبط</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button7" data-target="seven" class="btnliner">اخبار</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button8" data-target="eight" class="btnliner">تماس با ما</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="button9" data-target="nine" class="btnliner">درباره ما</button>
```

I didn't see the text fading, sorry. Anyway, you should not have the same code over and over, do a function at worst.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can handle all your buttons together instead of writing a separate piece of code for each:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnliner').on('click', function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
        $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
            $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
            $('.btnliner').css({
                "border": "hidden",
                "box-shadow": "2px 2px 10px #000"
            });
            btn.css({
                "border": "3px solid red",
                "box-shadow": "none"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/o1mzpmts/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o1mzpmts/9/).

And if you want this then add this code

```
.btnliner:active{
 background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/arpn52pnf/btnbg.jpg) no-repeat center -5px;
 }
```

Comment: he doesnt mean the box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Just filtered your JS Code, just replace your JS Code with mine

[Working:Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o1mzpmts/6/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
    var curId = this.id;
    $("button").css("border" , "hidden" );
    $("#"+curId).css("border","3px solid red");
    $("#"+curId).css("box-shadow","none");       
    });

});
```

Comment: Similar answers are already here.